# How to generate an automatic/dynamic name for a report in SQL Server Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0, report-builder2.0

I'm relatively new to SQL Server Report Builder and I'm curious if there is any way I can generate a dynamic/automatic name for a report.

For example my report name is ***"Order Status"*** and I want it to be like ***"Order Status 08.03.2015"*** where "08.03.2016" is the dynamic part. Since this report will be generated everyday I'm wondering if there is a way I can insert some sort of parameter to get me the date + the report name.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't put dynamic elements in a report name.   You can programmatically create and upload a new report and drop the old one every day though.   Look into BiML if that's the way you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

Create a textbox in your report and set the following expression:

```
="Order Status " & Format(Today(),"dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Today() function returns the date when report runs. If you run the report today it will show the today date.

It will show:

**Order Status 08.03.2016**

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That doesn't actually affect the _name_ of the report, though, does it?   I'm pretty sure that's what OP is asking for.

Comment: If OP means name of the RDL file as you pointed there is not way to achieve that from Report Builder. However He is not clarifying about that so in my opinion it is ambigous, also it could be a title or text for the name in the report. If that is not the case I'll delete my answer,

Comment: The suggestion helped me with another problem, but the question was about the name of the report when I export it from Report Builder to PDF or .XLS. I tried to edit the "ReportName" variable but I don't think it can be dynamic.